# How to generate a random vector for every batch in Tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, random, deep-learning

In the code here below the vector **rand** is initialized when I call the first time the function **create_model()**.

```
def create_model(num_columns):
    inp_layer = tfl.Input((num_columns,))
    rand = tf.random.uniform((1,num_columns), minval = 0, maxval = 2, dtype = tf.int32), tf.float32))
    inp_rand = tfl.Multiply()([inp_layer, rand])
    dense = tfl.Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(inp_rand)
    dense = tfl.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = tfl.Dense(64, activation = 'sigmoid')(dense)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inp_layer, outputs = dense)
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')

model = create_model(num_columns)
model.fit()
```

I would like it to be regenerated with new random values **every time I call the function model.fit()**, or even better, at any batch during the execution of model.fit().

Would you know how I can do this?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing in above code? If I understood your question correctly then you can generate the random number outside and pass it as a param to `create_model`

Comment: There is no problem with the code above. It works, but It doesn't work the way I want.
No, in that way, the random vector would be initialized only at the moment of the ```create_model``` call, which is exactly what I want to change.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for - https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question because you're (maybe incorrectly) presupposing part of the answer. Can you go back a step and explain your actual use case? If we set everything to random why is it not enough? Do you want to prevent  comparability between two random "instances"? "Instances" here could mean either two different batches or two different executions of fit? Lastly, are you aware how seeds work?

Comment: Answering to runDOSrun:
If I only set everything to random, I can generate a random vector at the moment I create my model. What I am implicitly supposing, is that this random vector won't change at every batch of training, nor if I run model.fit() several times. It will always be the same random vector generated at the creation of the model.
To answer your first question, I realized what I am trying to do is re-implementing Dropout Layer, so there is no point on doing that, I will just use the Dropout layer already available and close the question.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I was trying to implement is actually the Dropout layer. So no point in searching further.

Answer (score 1):

You can change what happens in the `call()` method of a subclassed Keras model.

```
    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        rand = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform((1, *x.shape[1:]), 0, 2, tf.int32), tf.float32)
        x = tf.multiply(x, rand)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.flatt(x)
        x = self.dens1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dens2(x)
        return x
```

Here I did it using the MNIST, where I multipled the input tensor with a random tensor of the same shape:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow import keras as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow import nn as nn
from functools import partial

dataset, info = tfds.load('mnist', with_info=True)

train, test = dataset['train'], dataset['test']

def prepare(dataset):
    inputs = tf.divide(x=dataset['image'], y=255)
    targets = tf.one_hot(indices=dataset['label'], depth=10)
    return inputs, targets

train = train.take(5_000).batch(4).map(prepare)
test = test.take(1_000).batch(4).map(prepare)

class MyCNN(K.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCNN, self).__init__()
        Conv = partial(Conv2D, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=nn.relu)
        MaxPool = partial(MaxPooling2D, pool_size=(2, 2))

        self.conv1 = Conv(filters=8)
        self.maxp1 = MaxPool()
        self.conv2 = Conv(filters=16)
        self.maxp2 = MaxPool()
        self.flatt = Flatten()
        self.dens1 = Dense(64, activation=nn.relu)
        self.drop1 = Dropout(.5)
        self.dens2 = Dense(10, activation=nn.softmax)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        rand = tf.cast(tf.random.uniform((1, *x.shape[1:]), 0, 2, tf.int32), tf.float32)
        x = tf.multiply(x, rand)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.flatt(x)
        x = self.dens1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        x = self.dens2(x)
        return x

model = MyCNN()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train, validation_data=test, epochs=10,
          steps_per_epoch=1250, validation_steps=250)
```